# Nativescript Accept Android SDK License

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-cli

currently I'm trying to get into NativeScript.

How Ever, running the command:

```
tns run android
```

gives me the following error message:

`You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
[Android SDK Build-Tools 25, Android SDK Platform 25]`

I already tried to completely uninstall Android SDK Build-Tools as well as SDK Platform and reinstall it using SDK Manager. It keeps prompting this error.

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of this, or how to accept the license correctly ?

I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem... But I solved it by executing the following.

```
android update sdk --no-ui --filter build-tools-25.0.0,android-25,extra-android-m2repository
```

I hope to help